# Python, os.system fails when script not in same folder

Tags: python, subprocess, pydev, os.system

I have a bat.bat file containing the following command: **'setup.py build'**

I have a script that executes this bat command using:
`os.system('E:/bla/FPtest/retryURL/Temp_installed/bat.bat'`

If i run the script from the same folder as the bat.bat ... it works perfectly perfectly.

If i run it in ANY other folder, the following error is returned.

```
**'setup.py'** is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have also tried `subprocess.Popen` which returns the same result **BUT** it includes this at the top: `C:\Eclipse\Workspace\example>setup.py build` ... mmmmmm ...

**UPDATE:**

I have decided to run the 
os.system command in the same directory where the bat.bat file is kept (this is ALSO the directory where the setup.py is stored)

the call should be so simply now.

```
import os
os.system('bat.bat')     note: (run from pydev)
```

**result:**

```
E:\App\FPtest\retryURL\Temp_installed>setup.py build 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python31\lib\site.py", line 56, in <module>
    import os
  File "C:\Python31\lib\os.py", line 380, in <module>
    from _abcoll import MutableMapping  # Can't use collections (bootstrap)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\_abcoll.py", line 49
    class Hashable(metaclass=ABCMeta):
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Additional note:

If i run any 'simple' .bat file everything works fine. and if i run the .bat file outside of the interpreter it too works fine ... which leads me to believe it is the content of the .bat file that is causing the problem the content is: `setup.py build`.
In this case the content of the .bat file executes an cx_freeze command to freeze and exe but the above error is what is returned when I try this

**UPDATE:**

It appears running the 'os.system('bat.bat')or the subprocess equivalent successfully executes the .bat file if run from the standard python interpreter. So it is only unsuccessful if run from Pydev

Comment: Where is `setup.py`? You need to either a) put the full path to `setup.py` in your `bat.bat` or b) add the folder containing `setup.py` to your PATH variable (in Linux: `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/folder/containing/setuppy`).

Comment: It seems a real cocktail for disaster. I am trying to run a bat file from pydev. which works normally. but I want have the bat file execute a cx_freeze to freeze another program. I have made a work around and moved on passed the above error but have encounted another one which i will add above

Comment: I am having a very similar issue with Pydev on Mac OS X--an exernal command that runs fine in the Python interpreter in the terminal, but not in Pydev.  I am highly interesting in understanding what's going wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a work around, which is infact more practical and efficient than my original question. I will accept this answer until solving the original question

Instead of using a .bat file ... Placing the content of the .bat file inside a .py subprocess works

import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('python -E setup.py build')

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 2000 and beyond the `.py` extension is associated with an open command that runs the interpreter. This is actually done during installation. But inorder to run the python script via the interpreter, either the script should be in the current directory or should be in one of the directories concatenated in the path environment variable.

In your case if setyp.py is present in present in some  and the path is absolute you can do the following

```
path=%path%;<directory containing setup.py>
```

On the other hand, if setup.py is at a relative directory from your batch file which is not an absolute path. You need to specify the full relative path from your current batch file location. Something like

```
..\<sub directory>\setyp.py #If the script is below the current path
```

or

```
.\<sup directory>\setyp.py #If the script is above the current path
```

Note*** You can also run the script without an extension (Not Recommend) if `.py` is present in the PATHEXT environment variable.

Comment: setup.py is not executing from the interpreter and I dont want it too. The .bat file is executing from the interpreter. setup.py is part of an cx_freeze command (located INSIDE the .bat file) and used to evoke cx_freeze to freeze an exe. I have also update the original post. thanks

Comment: now that you mention it the first line leading up to my new error is 'E:\Deepthroat\FPtest\retryURL\Temp_installed>setup.py build'... shouldn't it read 'E:\App\FPtest\retryURL\Temp_installed>bat.bat' The .bat file should be executing from the interpreter

Comment: @Rhys, Actually you are looking into the wrong place. The Bat file got executed correctly when when you ran the batch file and it tried to invoke "setup.py" without the python interpreter as the prefix, Windows tries to find the association of `py` with any open command. This is where it tries to search for setup.py and it fails to find it.

Comment: But how can it fail because when **I** manually run the .bat file without the interpreter, it works perfectly.

Comment: I have just discovered that running the 'os.system('bat.bat')or the subprocess equivalent successfully executes the .bat (And the bat file executes successfully too) if os.system is run from the standard python interpreter. it is only unsuccessful while using Pydev

Comment: Hi again, I got the following code to work subprocess.Popen('python -E setup.py build'). I dont even need a .bat file with this method. I have one last question which i think you were trying to explain... how can I include a destination for 'python -E setup.py build'. I'm trying this subprocess.Popen('E:/App/FPtest/retryURL/Temp_installed/python -E setup.py build') but it's not working. help please

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your path variable doesn't include either command. Try adding to your PATH environment variable the directory where both scripts reside.

In windows you do this by right clicking My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced (left pane in windows 7) -> Environment Variables. It's easier just to stick the path up front and make sure there's a ; between your entry and the start of the path variable as it is.... DON'T DELETE THE CONTENTS ALREADY THERE.

Comment: thanks, i started to become a little confused around 'It's easier just to stick' not your fault I'm unfamiliar with this- sorry